# Is there any way to export deployed reports from Cognos 10?

Tags: cognos-10

I want to understand is there any way to export published reports out of Cognos? We have another Cognos environment and want to publish the same reports which are available in the older version. I don't have the cognos project file (.cpf). So my assumption was if I can find that .cpf file from Cognos I can publish that package from the framework manager to the new cognos environment. I tried to search .cpf file in my cognos directory, but I only found the sample ones.

Is there any way to recover the published project file from Cognos?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a deployment of the reports & already published package to the other environment, so you don't need to do another publish.

You can recover the published model into a format when you can work in FM with it [see link here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-recover-corrupted-or-lost-framework-manager-model), results are variable in my experience.